# Bitbake image error for image with custom layer

Tags: ubuntu, embedded-linux

I'm following the digikey embedded linux series, I'm on part 4 and I keep getting this error when running bitbake custom-image:

```
ERROR: /home/matthew/Projects/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb: Error during parse `shell code, the last 5 lines are:
`       # iterate to the next setting
`       setting=`echo $remaining | cut -d ';' -f1``
`       remaining=`echo $remaining | cut -d ';' -f2-
`   done

`WARNING: /home/matthew/Projects/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb: Exception during `build_dependencies for set_user_group
`WARNING: /home/matthew/Projects/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb: Error during `finalise of /home/matthew/Projects/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb
`ERROR: Unable to parse /home/matthew/Projects/yocto/meta-custom/recipes-core/images/custom-image.bb
`Traceback (most recent call last):
`  File "/home/matthew/Projects/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/pysh/pyshlex.py", line 600, in `PLYLexer._parse(eof=True):
 `                elif self._state==self.ST_QUOTED:
 `   >                self._parse_quoted(eof)
 `                elif self._state==self.ST_HEREDOC:
`  File "/home/matthew/Projects/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/pysh/pyshlex.py", line 688, in `PLYLexer._parse_quoted(eof=True):
                 
    >        wtree, remaining = self._wordlexer.add(input, eof)
             self._wordlexer = None
`  File "/home/matthew/Projects/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/pysh/pyshlex.py", line 146, in `WordLexer.add(data=`['"', ' ', ']', ';', ' ', 't', 'h', 'e', 'n', '\n', '\t', '\t', '\t', 'b', 'r', 'e', 'a', 'k', '\n', '\t', `'\t', 'f', 'i', '\n', '\t', '\t', '#', ' ', 'i', 't', 'e', 'r', 'a', 't', 'e', ' ', 't', 'o', ' ', 't', `'h', 'e', ' ', 'n', 'e', 'x', 't', ' ', 's', 'e', 't', 't', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\n', '\t', '\t', 's', 'e', 't', `'t', 'i', 'n', 'g', '=', '`', 'e', 'c', 'h', 'o', ' ', '$', 'r', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' `', '|', ' ', 'c', 'u', 't', ' ', '-', 'd', ' ', "'", ';', "'", ' ', '-', 'f', '1', '`', '\n', '\t', '\t', `'r', 'e', 'm', 'a', 'i', 'n', 'i', 'n', 'g', '=', '`', 'e', 'c', 'h', 'o', ' ', '$', 'r', 'e', 'm', 'a', `'i', 'n', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', '|', ' ', 'c', 'u', 't', ' ', '-', 'd', ' ', "'", ';', "'", ' ', '-', 'f', `'2', '-', '`', '\n', '\t', 'd', 'o', 'n', 'e', '\n'], eof=True):
             self._buffer += list(data)
    >        self._parse(eof)
             
`  File "/home/matthew/Projects/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/pysh/pyshlex.py", line 324, in `WordLexer._parse(eof=True):
                     
    >            read, closed = parsefunc(buf, result, eof)
                     
`  File "/home/matthew/Projects/yocto/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/pysh/pyshlex.py", line 200, in `WordLexer._parse_dquote(buf=['\n', '\t', 'd', 'o', 'n', 'e', '\n'], result=['"', ' ]; `then\n\t\t\tbreak\n\t\tfi\n\t\t# iterate to the next setting\n\t\tsetting=', ['`', 'echo ', ['$', `'remaining', ''], ' | cut -d ', ["'", ';', "'"], ' -f1', '`'], '\n\t\tremaining=', ['`', 'echo ', ['$', `'remaining', ''], ' | cut -d ', ["'", ';', "'"], ' -f2-', '`'], ''], eof=True):`
             if pos==-1:
    >            raise NeedMore()
                 
`bb.pysh.pyshlex.NeedMore

`WARNING: /home/matthew/Projects/yocto/meta-st-stm32mp/recipes-st/images/st-image-vendorfs.bb: Cooker `received SIGTERM, shutting down...
`WARNING: /home/matthew/Projects/yocto/meta-st-stm32mp/recipes-security/optee/optee-os-stm32mp_3.12.0.bb: ``Cooker received SIGTERM, shutting down...
`WARNING: Cooker received SIGTERM, shutting down...

`Summary: There were 5 WARNING messages shown.
`Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```